# Postresql replication pg_basebackup no pg_hbaconf entry for replication connection

Tags: postgresql

I have updated my pg_hba on the master to this.

```
    host    loko     replicator      10.0.2.15/32               trust
```

and created a user with this command

```
    CREATE USER replicator REPLICATION LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'repl'
```

loko which is the databse on my master and replicator as the user.

and running this command on the slave

```
   pg_basebackup -h x.x.x.x -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\data" -U 
   replicator -v -P --write-recovery-conf -X stream
```

results to

> no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host  x.x.x.x.
>   user replicator, SSL off

Thanks a lot for any help. Im new to this so I don't have any idea whats wrong with this. I just followed a tutorial.

Comment: when I run pg_basebackup. the error I said on my question is the result.

Comment: did you reload postgres after changing hba?.. is x.x.x.x equal to 10.0.2.15?..

Comment: yes. it is equal.

Comment: ah. change loko database to replication

Answer (score 1):

Change database `loco` to `replication`:

```
 host    replication     replicator      10.0.2.15/32               trust
```

Comment: that was my first configuration but that doesnt work as well. Also, reading pg_hba.conf it says there that the replciation can be replaced by the database that you want to replicate over.

Comment: you cant replicate a database - it is always  a cluster

Comment: ok. already turned it back to replication but still getting the same error.

Comment: if you add `host    all     replicator      10.0.2.15/32               trust` and reload and `psql -h x.x.x.x  U replicator` you connect ok?.. maybe you connect over pgbouncer?.. whats your default port?

Comment: running that command results to Server closed the connection unexpectedly. This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request. postres is running on port 5432

Comment: ha. please specify postgres version and psql one

Comment: postgresql version is 9.4.